# How can I safely pass user GUI input data to a SwingWorker and work with that data?

Tags: java, thread-safety, parameter-passing, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

I'm confused about how to properly and safely pass data from GUI elements on the event-dispatch-thread (EDT) to a SwingWorker that needs to interact with that data.  I've followed the many examples on stackoverflow and around the web;  no matter which way I try to write, it seems like I'm breaking the oath to never touch GUI elements from a different thread.

I'll try to illustrate my confusion with pseudocode.

I've got a JFrame with some swing elements to take input from user.  User clicks a JButton, the JButton disables so user can't click it twice, and their input is passed to the SwingWorker in a background thread:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class GUI implements Runnable{
    JFrame jFrame;
    JTextField userInputTextField;
    JButton beginLongTaskButton;

    GUI(){
        //initialize the GUI elements, add them to JFrame, JPanel, etc.

        this.beginLongTaskButton = new JButton("Begin Task");
        this.beginLongTaskButton.addActionListener(a -> beginLongTask());//lambda sure is nice
    }

    void beginLongTask(){
        this.beginLongTaskButton.setEnabled(false);
        this.beginLongTaskButton.setText("Doing your long task...");
        LongTaskWorker longTaskWorker = new LongTaskWorker(this.userInputTextField);//isn't this bad?
        longTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        this.jFrame.setVisible(true);//blah blah
    }
}
```

At this moment, the EDT should be just be sitting pretty, except for one problem:  the SwingWorker was given some of the GUI elements via its constructor:

```
import javax.swing.*;

class LongTaskWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{
    JTextField userInputTextField;

    public LongTaskWorker(final JTextField userInputTextField){
        this.userInputTextField = userInputTextField;//the text field on EDT I'm not supposed to touch
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception{
        //read lots of stuff from JTextField in this Thread (the wrong thread)?
        //write? lots of stuff to JTextField in this Thread (the wrong thread)?
        //do lots of other stuff to JTextField?

        return null;
    }
}
```

I've seen many people do something similar to this.  I think even the JavaDoc SwingWorker example does it this way.  But doesn't it mean I'm messing with objects on a different thread when I'm not supposed to?  And does reading (not changing) the value of GUI components still violate the cross-threading rule? If my SwingWorker must frequently read data from GUI elements, won't that slow down the EDT?

Maybe the right thing to do is extract the data I need from the GUI elements within the EDT, then pass that extracted data to the SwingWorker?  As opposed to directly passing the GUI element to the SwingWorker.

Comment: Instead of passing the TextField, just pass its value and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By passing "its value," do you mean passing jTextField.getText()? I think this is what I mean by the last question I asked in my post. In my actual program I have 81 JTextFields that I've added to a HashMap, and that's what I need to pass and work with.

Comment: Exactly. Just pass the String from `getText()`. You need to pass the Hashmap? Could you explain that a little more detailed?

Comment: Sure. I'm working on a Sudoku puzzle solver, starting with the user interface. I don't know if you're familiar with Sudoku, but there are 9 rows and 9 columns of squares in which to write the numbers 1 through 9. I decided to make a HashMap<Integer, JTextField>(). The keys are integers 0 through 80 to identify a specific cell, and the values are the JTextFields on the GUI where the user inputs their data. This is the HashMap I was passing to the SwingWorker.  I suppose I'll just make a new HashMap<Integer, String>() where the Strings are the JTextField.getText()'s, and pass that to SwingWorker

Comment: It just feels like I could do this a better way. Also, please consider making your first comment an answer to my question. I'll mark it as correct in a couple days.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually might want is a Model for your View. That is: The View as name suggests is your GUI and its elements - the JTextFields. Your Model would be a backing Map of the 81 Values. Now if you want to compute something on it, you'd pass the backing Map to that method (SwingWorker). If something changes the backing Model, an Event should trigger the GUI to refresh (load values from Model). If the user changes a value in the GUI, that change should be made through a controller. It in turn changes the Model and initiates the Change-Event.

This way you also can avoid feedback-loops.

You can read about this concept looking for "MVC" or "Model View Controller".

Comment: I'd never heard of this MVC kind of design strategy, but you opened up a whole new world of possibilities to accomplish what I want. I have a bit of learning to do about this, it looks really cool. Thanks very much for your suggestion! I'll eventually mark your answer correct if it works.